# Android Studio debugging options disabled

Tags: android, android-studio

Sometimes when I hit debug and run it using GennyMotion's emulator, the debugging options "step over, step out etc" stay disabled. Any clue ? 
I'm using Android Studio 0.8.9, and in updates I only have dev updates enabled not beta.

[image: Android Studio debugging]

Comment: You can't do much if the app isn't stopped at a breakpoint. Are your breakpoints working?

Comment: @ScottBarta The program does stop but I don't know where, if you look at Frames section in debugger, its not showing any processes. Restart does solve it though.